# Invariant cardinal over $\aleph_1$.

Tags: set-theory

I'm studying about invariant cardinals and theirs natural generalizations to uncountable cardinals. I was reading  a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195509782) which focus over splitting number $\mathfrak{s}(\kappa)$ and there I found the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $\kappa$ be a uncountable cardinal. $\mathfrak{s}(\kappa)\geq\kappa$ iff $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccesible cardinal.

In particular, I'm interesting in the case when $\kappa=\aleph_1$ and it is clear that the theorem above implies that $\mathfrak{s}(\aleph_1)=\aleph_0$. But I want to get a direct proof of this fact however, I have troubles to achieve it.

I don't want a solution of my problem, I only need some suggest or advice to see my problem since another perspective. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider an $\aleph_1$ sized subset $X$ of $2^\omega$ and the sets $\{x \in X: s \subseteq x \}$ for $s \in 2^{<\omega}$.

Comment: I can see how your hint works. In fact, the same argument holds if I take $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $|X|=\aleph_1$ and I consider the family $\{(p,q):p,q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. But I have a doubt with respect a this solution, why can I translate my problem to sets with size $\mathfrak{c}$ as $2^{\omega}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?